# Cómo mandar mensaje a whatsapp desde PHP

Tags: php, whatsapp, mensajes

busco una forma de enviar mensajes de notificación a clientes a su Whatsapp, Tengo un sistema de ventas, y busco que cada que se actualice el estado de la compra, se mande al numero del cliente esa notificación, conocen alguna forma de lograrlo sin requerir pagar a terceros? o es imposible?

Comment: @marcos ya investigue, pero requiere utilizar un servicio tercero, gracias por responder de todas formas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por experiencia te puedo decir que es imposible. Antes hubo alguien que desarrolló una librería de PHP en que a través de un token que generabas podías enviar mensajes a través de WhatsApp. Pero como siempre pasa en estos casos, WhatsApp se enteró, denunció y obligó a cerrar el proyecto (que estaba colgado en GitHub).

Por desgracia no hay nada gratuito, todo son plataformas de terceros, así que toca pagar o utilizar WhatsApp Web (eso de escanear el código QR) pero esto último es bastante rollo...